# Is it true that the potential method is usually the inverse of the accounting method in the context of amortized analysis?

Tags: amortized-analysis

I remember reading this somewhere (will post the source as soon as I find it), but was wondering, if anyone knows why this is true or has maybe an example to portray why this is the case.

Comment: I think you need to flesh out your question.  What do you mean by "inverse"?  What have you tried?  Have you tried looking at some examples to see if this seems to be the case for them?

Comment: @D.W. yep, I will. Let me see again where I read this, so I can provide a better explanation.